# the inner for loop does not work after the 1st iteratin of the outer for loop

Tags: php

I try to insert values from a database into a 2d array in php, but the inner for loop does not work after the 1st iteration of the outer loop. Here is the code

```
for ($i=0; $i<$recCount; $i++) {            
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);             
            $orderNo[$i]        = $row['orderNo'];
            $orderDate[$i]      = $row['orderDate'];
            $subTotal[$i]       = $row['subTotal'];
            $discount[$i]       = $row['discount'];
            $deliveryCharge[$i] = $row['deliveryCharge'];
            $grandTotal[$i]     = $row['grandTotal'];           
            $k = 0;
            for ($j=0; $j<$recCount2; $j++){
                $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);                 
                $orderNo2[$i][$j]           = $row2['orderNo'];
                echo "orderNo2[$i][$j]: " .$orderNo2[$i][$j]. "&nbsp";
                if ($orderNo2[$i][$j] == $orderNo[$i]){
                    /*$subNo($i,$k)         = $row2['subNo'];
                    $ItemNo($i,$k)          = $row2['ItemNo'];
                    $Description($i,$k) = $row2['Description'];
                    $Qty($i,$k)         = $row2['Qty'];         
                    $Price($i,$k)           = $row2['Price'];
                    $Amount($i,$k)          = $row2['Amount'];*/
                    $k++;
                }
            }
```

$recCount = 3, $orderNo[$i] has the value of 1, 2, 3. $recCount2 = 15, the $orderNo2[$i][$j] should have five 1s, five 2s, and five 3s for each $i, but the echoed result of orderNo2 is

orderNo2[0][0]: 1 orderNo2[0][1]: 1 orderNo2[0][2]: 1 orderNo2[0][3]: 1 orderNo2[0][4]: 1 orderNo2[0][5]: 2 orderNo2[0][6]: 2 orderNo2[0][7]: 2 orderNo2[0][8]: 2 orderNo2[0][9]: 2 orderNo2[0][10]: 3 orderNo2[0][11]: 3 orderNo2[0][12]: 3 orderNo2[0][13]: 3 orderNo2[0][14]: 3 orderNo2[1][0]:  orderNo2[1][1]:  orderNo2[1][2]:  orderNo2[1][3]:  orderNo2[1][4]:  orderNo2[1][5]:  orderNo2[1][6]:  orderNo2[1][7]:  orderNo2[1][8]:  orderNo2[1][9]:  orderNo2[1][10]:  orderNo2[1][11]:  orderNo2[1][12]:  orderNo2[1][13]:  orderNo2[1][14]:  orderNo2[2][0]:`enter code here`  orderNo2[2][1]:  orderNo2[2][2]:  orderNo2[2][3]:  orderNo2[2][4]:  orderNo2[2][5]:  orderNo2[2][6]:  orderNo2[2][7]:  orderNo2[2][8]:  orderNo2[2][9]:  orderNo2[2][10]:  orderNo2[2][11]:  orderNo2[2][12]:  orderNo2[2][13]:  orderNo2[2][14]:

After $i = 1, the later ones are all empty. I don't know why the inner for loop does not work after the 1st outer for loop iteration

Comment: what's the value for $recCount2 ?

Comment: the value is 15, as the database has 15 rows of dataset

Comment: I suspect this is a case of not seeing `E_NOTICE` level errors. Please check [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: I have tried to add the codes from the link you provided into my file, but no error popped out, ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
 ini_set('html_errors', 0);
 error_reporting(E_All);

Comment: @Jack, "the value is 15, as the database has 15 rows of dataset " is actually expectation/assumption based on what you were trying to do.

when something like this happens, you have to really see what the value is so... 

var_dump($recCount2); exit;

if it is not 15, as you expected. then find out why it is so.